# magento display request url

Tags: url, magento, content-management-system, controller, request

i wanted to display the module,controller,method being called

i thought that the cms module found in the

> app\code\core\Mage\cms\

calls the IndexController.php and uses the IndexAction method .since it is the default page url.

but when I tried to echo out something inside the IndexAction method .nothing comes out. I even tried to call it manually and it still redirects to the home page.

> localhost/magento/index.php/cms/index/index/

am i doing it right?
how can i display the request url being called in magento?

Comment: the "i" of indexAction should be lowercase

Comment: yup all of it are lower case. indexController and indexAction .

Comment: well, IndexController should be UpperCase :) -> Namespace_Module_IndexController extends ... and IndexController.php

Answer (score 11):

I was looking for this also, here's how to do it:

```
echo Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
```

Comment: This is really useful for getting the full request URL.

Answer (score 9):

Hi you could try to output the following

```
<?php
    echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName();
    echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
    echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();
?>
```

Not tested but maybe you can do something like this

```
<?php
    echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
?>
```

Hope this helps

greetings

Comment: echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestUri(); - is legit, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I needed the URL segments, so I used this:

```
function getUrlSegment($i) {
    $_baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
    $_currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
    $_path = str_replace($_baseUrl, '', $_currentUrl);
    $_segments = explode('/', rtrim($_path, '/'));
    return $_segments[$i];
}

// Would get 'store' if URL: http://example.com/store/product/123
$root = getUrlSegment(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting 'headers already sent' warnings in your log files using an echo in the controller. Instead of using echo use Mage::log, e.g.

```
Mage::log('My request url is: '.$requestUrl);
```

The log line should appear in the /var/logs/system.log file.

Comment: where should i put it? i tried putting it in the head.phtml .i don't know in what controller to put it.

Answer (score 0):

The route `cms/index/index` is only ever used for the home page. Other standard pages like "no-route" and "enable-cookies" are optionally handled by specific actions on the IndexController. The remaining pages are handled by `Mage_Cms_PageController::viewAction()` instead. Try the path [cms/page/view/id/customer-service](http://localhost/magento/index.php/cms/page/view/id/customer-service) to see. The parameter is `id` and so the next term `customer-service` is the page identifier which you set in the admin as "URL Key".